# R Function error

Tags: r, function, user-defined-functions

I have a dataset with 17 variables, all of them integer/num.
For a better descriptive analysis I created this user defined function :

```
 sum <- function(x)
  {
    na.len<-sum(is.na(x))
    mean<-mean(x,na.rm=T)
    sd<-sd(x,na.rm=T)
    min<-min(x,na.rm=T)
    q1<-quantile(x,0.25,na.rm=T)
    q3<-quantile(x,0.75,na.rm=T)
    max<-max(x,na.rm=T)
    UC1=mean+3*sd
    LC1=mean-3*sd
    UC2=quantile(x,0.99,na.rm=T)
    LC2=quantile(x,0.01,na.rm=T)
    iqr=IQR(x,na.rm=T)
    UC3=q3+1.5*iqr
    LC3=q1-1.5*iqr
    ot<-max>UC1 | min<LC1 | max>UC2 | min<LC2 | max>UC3 | min<LC3
    x[x>max]<-max
    x[x<min]<-min
    out_exist <- ifelse(noofNA > 0, "outlier_exists", "")
    return(c(noofNA=na.len,mean=mean,std=sd,min=min,q1=q1,q3=q3,max=max,outlier=ot, out_exists= out_exist))
  }
```

When I use this function on my dataset using :

```
apply(df, 2, sum)
```

I get following error :

> Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion /
>   options(expressions=)? Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too
>   deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?

I am trying to understand what's the issue but all in vain, please help!

Comment: If you are asking why this code doesn't work, it should be included with a minimum reproducible example.  I would also recommend to split the function into small parts and find where it is not working.

Comment: You named your function `sum`, then inside it, you call the function `sum` to perform summation. Change the name of your function.

Comment: Also, don't do like this `mean<-mean(x,na.rm=T)`, instead of naming result `mean` try using something like this: `meanResult <- mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Proof: `sum <- function(x){ sum(x) }; sum(1)`. `Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?`

Comment: I updated the function :

Comment: Thanks, I got your point and updated the function : `sum` - `detail` , `min/max` - `min/max_res` , `mean - m` , `sd - std`. But am still getting the same error.

Comment: What are `sum - detail`, `min/max`...?

Comment: Sorry, so I changed the function name from `sum` to `detail` and likewise for some variables which I used inside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how your function should look like. But you didn't define `noofNA`, so you will still get an error.

```
details <- function(x)
{
  na.len <- sum(is.na(x))
  m <- mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)
  s <- sd(x, na.rm=TRUE)
  mn <- min(x, na.rm=TRUE)
  q1 <- quantile(x, 0.25, na.rm=TRUE)
  q3 <- quantile(x, 0.75, na.rm=TRUE)
  mx <- max(x, na.rm=TRUE)
  UC1 <- m+3*s
  LC1 <- m-3*s
  UC2 <- quantile(x, 0.99, na.rm=TRUE)
  LC2 <- quantile(x, 0.01, na.rm=TRUE)
  iqr <- IQR(x, na.rm=TRUE)
  UC3 <- q3+1.5*iqr
  LC3 <- q1-1.5*iqr
  ot <- mx>UC1 | mn<LC1 | mx>UC2 | mn<LC2 | mx>UC3 | mn<LC3
  x[x>mx]<-mx
  x[x<mn]<-mn
  out_exist <- ifelse(noofNA > 0, "outlier_exists", "")
  return(list(noofNA=na.len, mean=m, std=s, min=mn, q1=q1, q3=q3, max=mx, outlier=ot, out_exists= out_exist))
}

set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))
sapply(df1, details)
```